# What is the right approach for state change?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement this in my app:

**Original code:**

```
<Searchbox change={this.onSearchChange}/>
```

But this is not working. While trying several options, I found following codes work:

**Code 1:**

```
<Searchbox change={event => setState({/*the state is changed*/})}/>
```

**Code 2:**

```
<Searchbox change={event => this.onSearchChange(event)}/>
```

Reading the documentation, I believe I wrote the correct syntax in the first time, but I want to be sure.

Comment: Maybe nice to add is that `change={this.onSearchChange}` only refers to the function, which looses the value of `this` when you call it (unless additional code provides how to get to `this`, lookup binding if you're interested). The last option calls the function directly, so you'll have access to `this` inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in the React documentation. I should have put this in the constructor:

```
this.onSearchChange = this.onSearchChange.bind(this)
```

Because, in the child component, it does not detect the function from parent for `this` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Searchbox change={event => this.onSearchChange(event)}/>
```

This a better option if you want to do any kinds of valiadation/ modification before setting the state in `onSearchChange`

Answer (score 0):

Your **Original Code** and **Code 2** are the same. You need to check again what was your actual issue with **Original Code** that is was not working